Fidelity bound under composed channels?
Suppose $\mathcal{E}_1, \mathcal{E}_2$ are CPTP maps. Is the following bound true?
$$F(\mathcal{E}_1 \circ \mathcal{E}_2 (\rho), \rho) \stackrel{?}{\geq} F(\mathcal{E}_1(\rho), \rho) + F(\mathcal{E}_2(\rho), \rho) - 1\,.$$
If it helps, one can assume $\rho$ is pure.

Take $\mathcal{E}_1 = \mathcal{U}_{\theta_1}$ and $\mathcal{E}_2 = \mathcal{U}_{\theta_2}$, where $\mathcal{U}_\theta$ conjugates $\rho$ by the X-rotation $U(\theta) = e^{i \theta X}$. Then,
\begin{align}
  F(\mathcal{E}_1 \circ \mathcal{E}_2(|0\rangle \langle 0|)) = |\langle 0 | e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)X}| 0\rangle|^2 &= \cos^2(\theta_1 + \theta_2)\\
F(\mathcal{E}_1 (|0\rangle \langle 0|)) &= \cos^2(\theta_1),
\end{align}
and your question becomes whether the following is true:
$$
\cos^2(\theta_1 + \theta_2) \stackrel{?}{\geq} \cos^2(\theta_1) + \cos^2(\theta_2) - 1.
$$
This is false for $\theta_1=\theta_2=\frac{\pi}{6}$, for instance.
